# Eclipse dissapears when minimized and will not come back (12.04 Unity)

Tags: 12.04, unity, eclipse

I have Ubuntu 12.04 x64 running Unity3d. I downloaded Eclipse from eclipse.org (not the software center) and created a desktop using gnome-desktop-item-edit. The resulting file is below, and I added it to the launcher on the left of the screen by dragging that file on.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/home/kevin/eclipse/icon.xpm
Name[en_US]=Eclipse
Exec=/home/kevin/eclipse/eclipse
Name=Eclipse
Icon=/home/kevin/eclipse/icon.xpm#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

However, when I minimize eclipse, eclipse disappears. There is no arrow to the left of the icon in the launcher like usual. And when I click on the launcher again, it tries to relaunch eclipse instead of bringing back the one that was minimized. Eclipse also does not show up when I alt-tab.

I know it is still running because I can see it running with the system monitor.

Note that Eclipse works properly until it is minimized. I have observed this behavior on two different computers now. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Does it show up if you press Alt+Tab?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer further down the thread that Surya pointed me to. See this [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/748516/comments/19).

To describe the fix:

1. Launch alacarte
2. Click Programming on the left
3. Click New Item on the right
4. Enter Eclipse in the Name field
5. Enter the location of the eclipse binary in the Command field
6. Open bamf.index (sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/bamf.index)
7. Insert the line "Eclipse ~/path/to/eclipse" (where you substitute /path/to with the actual path). There was no Eclipse entry in my bamf.index. If there is an entry, you may want to try editing that entry instead of making a new one.
8. Log out, log back in
9. Launch eclipse using the unity application lense
10. Now you can pin the eclipse launcher to the dock, and minimizing also works.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses [Bamf Application Matching Framework](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/common-libraries/#bamf) for matching application. There is an issue when an older version of eclipse is replaced with a new version.

Please check the comment given [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/748516/comments/16) on how to fix the bamf.index file to fix the tab issue